# Awk multiply column by a specific value

Tags: arrays, awk

I'm quite new to awk, that I am using more and more to process the output files from a model I am running. Right now, I am stuck with a multiplication issue.

I would like to calculate relative change in percentage.

Example:

```
  A B
1 150 0
2 210 10
3 380 1000
...
```

I would like to calculate `Ax = (Ax-A1)/A1 * 100`.

Output:

```
  New_A B
1 0 0
2 10 40
3 1000 153.33
...
```

I can multiply columns together but don't know how to fix a value to a position in the text file (ie. Row 1 Column 1).

Thank you.

Comment: `A B` is my input file, ideally I would like an output such as `B Calculated_A`. I would do this in Excel or Matlab, but I will have quite a few files so scripting the process would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your actual file does not have the "A B" header and the row numbers in it:

```
$ cat file
150 0
210 10
380 1000
$ awk 'NR==1 {a1=$1} {printf "%s %.1f\n", $2, ($1-a1)/a1*100}' file | column -t
0     0.0
10    40.0
1000  153.3
```